# Partially distinct select

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table with fields `utm` and `tracking_id`. There may be many `tracking_id`s for each `utm`.
So I need to select distinct utm and any one tracking id for each utm (let`s say thefirst one).

For example, we got the table:

```
utm   | tracking_id
-------------------
ddff  |      1
ddff  |      2
llzz  |      3
ddff  |      4
ohoh  |      5
ohoh  |      6
```

And as an output i want to get:

```
utm   | tracking_id
-------------------
ddff  |      1
llzz  |      3
ohoh  |      5
```

I use PostgreSQL 9.1.
Is there a way to do it with SQL?

Comment: so you want the lowest tracking_id for each group of utm entities, right?

Comment: I think he wants a parameterized way, so he can choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have only one column, than simple aggregate is what you want, go with Clodoaldo Neto's advice.
If you have more than one columns, you can use [dictinst on](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) syntax:

```
select distinct on(utm)
    utm, tracking_id, column1, column2, ...
from t
order by utm, tracking_id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1e933/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 5):

```
select utm, min(tracking_id)
from t
group by utm
```

Comment: Tracking_id is not present in the group by clause. This is a not valid SQL statement.